# MongoDB: удалить данные из массива

Tags: mongodb, массивы, update

Имеется массив в коллекции

```
"contact" : {
        "name" : "Имя",
        "phone" : [
            {
                "number" : "номер",
                "_id" : ObjectId("53c87c6f967fb6532a95954e"),
                "call" : {
                    "until" : "0:00",
                    "later" : "0:00"
                }
            },
            {
                "number" : "номер 2",
                "_id" : ObjectId("53c87c6f967fb6532a95954d"),
                "call" : {
                    "until" : "0:00",
                    "later" : "0:00"
                }
            },
            {
                "number" : "номер 3",
                "_id" : ObjectId("53c87c6f967fb6532a95954c"),
                "call" : {
                    "until" : "0:00",
                    "later" : "0:00"
                }
            }
        ],
```

Пишу запрос на удаление

```
db.table.update({ 'contact.phone._id': ObjectId("53c87c6f967fb6532a95954d")}, { '$pull': { 'contact.phone._id': ObjectId("53c87c6f967fb6532a95954d") } })
```

Получаю сообщение

```
WriteResult({
    "nMatched" : 0,
    "nUpserted" : 0,
    "nModified" : 0,
    "writeError" : {
        "code" : 16837,
        "errmsg" : "cannot use the part (phone of contact.phone._id) to traverse the element ({phone: [ { number: \"номер\", _id: ObjectId('53c87c6f967fb6532a95954e'), call: { until: \"0:00\", later: \"0:00\" } }, { number: \"номер2\", _id: ObjectId('53c87c6f967fb6532a95954d'), call: { until: \"0:00\", later: \"0:00\" } }, { number: \"номер3\", _id: ObjectId('53c87c6f967fb6532a95954c'), call: { until: \"0:00\", later: \"0:00\" } } ]})"
    }
})
```

Как удалить из массива

```
{
                "number" : "номер",
                "_id" : ObjectId("53c87c6f967fb6532a95954d"),
                "call" : {
                    "until" : "0:00",
                    "later" : "0:00"
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение:

```
db.table.update({"_id": ObjectId("53c15d98aa4719f45076d5ed")}, {"$pull": { "contact.phone": {"_id": ObjectId("53c8b57ea9f447680b217dd6")} } })
```